# BPT - Environment Purposes vs. Publishing Target Dialog box

Tags: publishing

**Background**

---

Here is the Business Process Type

[image]

> We have a Business Process Type that defines all Purposes [Live, Preview, Preview2]. In Publication A all 3 Purposes are enabled and used; however only 2 Purposes are used in Publication B & C; but all 3 display in Publish Dialog Box

**Publication A**

1. Live
2. Preview
3. Preview2

**Publication B**

1. Live
2. Preview

**Publication C**

1. Live
2. Preview

...

---

**Problem / Question**

Since there are implementation specific reasons that they share a bpt in 8.5; how can we prevent **Publication B** or **C** or *any Publication* that **does not** have all enabled Purposes on the BPT from showing in the Publishing Dialog Box?

Seems like a product defect. It shouldn't display a target if it is not being used downstream on the publication.

[image]

> It's a dead target. It is not enabled; but still displays for the user. Doesn't go anywhere..(for that publication)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke with @Jon on a few ideas that would definitely work as well - Thanks Jon!

However, it seemed like the best solution for me would be to just utilize the security model though the `business process type` - in order to hide the target from the publish Dialog box.

Simple and no deployment needed.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create a new `Topology Type` (and `Topology`) that only has the two purposes that you want (*Preview* and *Live*).

You can then create a new `Business Process Type` (BPT) within the Content Manager, select your new `Topology Type` for this and then use this BPT for Publications B and C (and any others that only need the two publishing options).

---

**Update:** You mention that 'Since there are implementation specific reasons that they share a bpt in 8.5;'.

Although you can't do this is the CME GUI, you can update your new BPT using the Core Service so that it uses your old Target Types. You may want to take a look at the code sample on this page as a starter: https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/sdl-web-8-migrating-from-old-to-new-style-publishing-part-3-of-3-extending-business-process-types

Comment: Yes. I actually used that for migration from 2013 to 8.5. If you have targets that span an instance of 100+ web publications.. that would be quite a lot of services to maintain, agree?

Comment: I am not even quite sure you can use the exact same DS url if you went this route. There are a lot of limitations with TopMan in my use case that I don’t think was ever considered.

Comment: Hey Andrew. I'm not sure I understand this bit: "that would be quite a lot of services to maintain, agree?". Can you clarify please? 
I think that you would just create one new BPT (that reuses the old Target Types) high up in your BluePrint and re-use this on lots of Publications.

Comment: I don't think you'd change the CD side at all. Your new Topology will point to the two existing Discovery Services (one for Preview and one for Live). I've never had to do this (have two Topologies point to a single Discovery Service), but don't see why it would cause a problem.

Comment: Ok if you talking about using same DS endpoints, but with new Topology’s; I’ll have to test n see

Comment: If you update the new BPT to use the old Target Types (using the Core Service), I’m intrigued to hear whether “Also publish in child publications” (in the publishing dialogue) still works when having a mix of publications using the old and new Topology Types.