# How do CMS users see Publishing Targets?

Tags: web8, publishing, cme

CMS users while publishing can see two targets in our case: Staging and Live.

How can we restrict users to publish only to Staging? Where are the settings to allow users to publish or view only Staging targets but not Live?

Comment: Similar question. but I only got 2 pts for my answer lol https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19349/bpt-environment-purposes-vs-publishing-target-dialog-box/19362#19362

Comment: Thanks Andrew for that link, it helped me  understand  more

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are specified in the **Security** section of the Business Process Type (for each Purpose).

The Business Process type is then included in the **Publishing** section of the Publication Properties.

[image]